# How to horizontally align columns within a div

Tags: html, css, grid

I have three `<figure>` tags and I want to align them horizontally within my `container` div. I tried the method with float left, right and margin auto but didn't work. What should I do?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </figure>

  <figure class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </figure>

  <figure class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </figure>
</div>
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/gsg/pen/NGGjYQ)**

Comment: Seems fine to me, or do you want them all together?

Comment: @jaunt +1. GSG, What exactly you want? What problem you are facing?

Comment: @GSG I have posted the answer, i think it might help you.

Comment: They are not horizontally aligned. They should have the same margin distance both in right and in the left(right now there isn't a left margin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the images within your div, try this:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

And here's your amended codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwwdmP

Answer (score 0):

You just need is `overflow:auto;` for your `container` class.

Posted the solution to both your code and the updated see the difference. For instance added the `border:1px solid red;` to see the difference.

**Solution**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {  
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow:auto; /*added*/
}

.col {    
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure class="col"">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">    
  </figure>

  <figure class="col"">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">    
  </figure>

  <figure class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">    
  </figure>
</div>
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvvwMz)

**Your Code Snippet**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {  
  width: 100%;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.col {    
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure class="col"">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">    
  </figure>

  <figure class="col"">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">    
  </figure>

  <figure class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">    
  </figure>
</div>
```